# How can community do downvotes?

Tags: discussion

How could community downvote or upvote any questions or answer?

On its [profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) it claims that it is not really a person but it's total downvotes are 11,168 . And it's last seen was Nov 1'10

Answer (score 5):

Did you read the profile? It literally says how this is possible: One of the things it does is:

> Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted

Comment: The OP does have an interesting observation there, though - the `last seen` property of the Community user seems to point to the start of private beta for each SE site, which is probably the most readily available mark of the site's birthdate.